# Hiding empty columns and rows with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm searching the answer for that, but find out nothing yet.
I'm migrating a report, which was done manually so far, to a automatic job using apache poi.

In the original report it shows the report cells, lets say from cell A1 to AC186 and all others cols and rows are hiden.

See a image showing it here: http://img.chandoo.org/q/show-only-few-rows-and-columns-in-excel.png

I've tested some codes from the web, but still not getting that.
To hide the cols I tried this code:

```
for (int i = mylastReportCol; i <= 16384; i++) {
    sheet.setColumnHidden(i, true);
}
```

But still not working.

Have anyone ever tried the same with poi??

Comment: Have you tried setting the column width to 0? `workSheet.setColumnWidth(i,0)`.

Comment: what do you mean by `setColumnHidden` not working? result still the same or there is any exception?

Comment: Well, it means that the collumns were still visible in generated file, although no exception ocurred.

Comment: I managed to find a way to something like for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326333/hide-all-extra-excel-columns-with-apache-poi/37328347#37328347

Comment: I tried the code you mentioned and it is working fine.